# How to automatically disconnect when mains voltage is on connection?

Tags: ac, mains, protection

I have this very specific problem and can't think of a simple solution for it, maybe some of you have an idea how to tackle my problem.

So basically what I want to do is have 2 mains connectors, each with a little box containing a µController and some hardware inside. The first box is more or less complete, it contains a 230V~/5+3.3V converter, an ESP for web based energy logging and some parts that go along it. On the other side I don't have much room for components, but I basically want some circuitry that contains an ID the ESP has to check and transmit to the server. The problem now is that I would have to communicate over the powerlines. I'm planning on using the 1-wire interface, essentially needing 2 wires, which I have. That way I wouldn't have to put anything in the second plug except for the 1-wire EEPROM.

When I plug one plug into the other, there is no 230V~, they can freely communicate over the power lines. Then the ESP schould turn on the 230V.
My problem now is, how do I protect the 1-wire part and the ESP from the 230V once activated?

Here's a little schematic to show what I discribed:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCNSrk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The red box is where I would have to add this protection, some way to disconnect the 1-Wire Data and GND line from the AC line.

Biggest problem: The circuit in plug 1 is fixed and I dont exactly know how they build it, but I can only design the circuit inside plug 2!
The PCB in plug 2 can't be bigger as 4x5cm as well..

Does anyone have an idea how to manage this?

EDIT:

I just thought of a switching relay..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUXqN0.png)</sup>

The relay would switch as soon as a voltage bigger than  whatever I communicate at (probably 10 or 12V) is applied, disconnecting the IC with one pin from mains, which should be enough as only one potential is attached now. But the circuit would probably just fry my IC before the switch is made so that wont help..

Comment: "The circuit in plug 1 is fixed" - this causes a lot of problems. Are you trying to interface with an existing product? If it's fixed, there must be a corresponding Plug 2 that already exists which you can reverse-engineer?

Comment: I'm working together with another person and he designed plug 1. As we already have a few of his PCB produced we want to make something that works with it. There is no working counterpart yet.

Comment: Does plug 1 even work? It appears to have 230V AC being fed into its 3.3V supply.

Comment: I was missing the switch, thank you. the switch is controlled by the ESP as well. I'd need such switches inside plug 2 as well, but there would be no way to controll them..

Comment: I **strongly discourage you** from using the same power lines (even if of course in different times) as both 220V input, and as low voltage communication media. 
This could fry your 1-Wire device when you don't make a good connection with the mains. (the contacts between a plug are not ideal, and "bounces" or metastates might occur). Remember also that the relay release time is not zero. Can't you use any optical transmission instead?

Comment: You need some way to ID the plug when it is not powered. Have you considered [RFID](http://scanlime.org/2008/09/using-an-avr-as-an-rfid-tag/)?

Comment: Producing one half of the system without even *designing* the other is a colossal mistake. If starting from scratch, I would investigate some kind of AC-coupled high-frequency system, which would allow you to speak to the IC without having to disconnect the power but at the same time being properly isolated from it.